# Rest Api calls from frontend to backend when information is inside other microsercives

Tags: microservices

I am looking for best answer to I think typical issue when, there is a frontend calling backend ( some api gateway )  and that gateway needs to get information from microservice A ( ie: its GET request ), but that microservice needs also to call other microservice B.
It can lag of course.

IMO its bad architecture design, and better would be that microservice B after having some information should push that into kafka topic on which MS A would listen to, and keep copy of that needed data.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

You said the correct thing "it can lag...". The question is if that would be a problem. And if it would be a problem, how likely is that lag?

Just a scenario to play through a few thoughts. Think about a wonderful frontend that makes use of a few hundred microservices. Not very likely, but extremes help to find issues :-)

Now, in my scenario your frontend handles all those connections directly. That means it has to KNOW all microservices
=> your whole application structure is known to the frontend. And is accessible from the internet. That means you have to harden and guard them all, because of the bad guys out there.

If a microservice needs to change its API, then the frontend has to adapt. That means you have to ensure that the frontends out there will update and not use the old API.

Also now the frontend is the one who has to have the knowledge what to do if a request fails.

Also, a a lot of connections means a lot of traffic overhead. As a result a lot of the data traffic the client produces is just overhead. May be a problem on a mobile connection with limited traffic.

Depending on where the microservices are located, it may be that the connection to each microservice consists out of the connection from the client to your company network and then the routing in your company. It is very likely that the part "client->company" is the slow part. The part "company gateway -> microservice" is the one that you can optimize. Therefore it could be that calling the microservices directly is slower than if its done behind closed curtains.

---

My advise (without knowing the details of your requirements) would be to "hide" most microservice calls behind your own backend. That also wil handle eventual CORS-issues.
IF performance is a problem for some microservices, then we could still move them into the frontend.

**But at the end, there is no silver bullet.**
An application which uses its "own" microservices" may need a different handling than one which uses public ones. The application with millions of users will have different priorities than the specific high end application for expert users in you company.

Check your requirements, check the context in which the application will run. Then think different scenarios through and note down the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "good architecture" and "bad architecture", only "architecture that meets your requirements" and "architecture which doesn't".

If multiple HTTP calls meets your requirements, then it's fine. Don't overcomplicate your system because you read a blog post somewhere saying "never make 2 HTTP calls". Of course, if multiple HTTP calls doesn't meet your requirements, then you need something else.